# Problems writing to a unix pipe through Java

Tags: java, pipe, outputstream

I am writing to a framebuffer located at "/dev/fb0". Everything works fine until I try to write again to the pipe using an OutputStream, which hangs the program. I have resolved this by closing the output stream and then recreating it, but this seems awfully slow and blunt.

`Framebuffer.java`

```
public class Framebuffer extends Autobuffer {
private FileOutputStream out = null;
private File pipe = null;

public Framebuffer() {
   super(320, 240);
}

public Framebuffer(File pipe) {
   super(320, 240);
   try {
      out = new FileOutputStream(pipe);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 this.pipe = pipe;
 }

 public void sync() throws IOException {
   out.write(getBytes());
   out.close();
   out = new FileOutputStream(pipe);
 }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, unless something really weird is going on, "/dev/fb0" is a device file not a pipe. [This is a nitpick, but if you use the wrong terminology, 1) people won't understand you and 2) you will have difficulty searching for answers.]

Secondly, this looks like a weird way to interact with a framebuffer!!

I suspect that the problem is that you need to do the equivalent of a POSIX `lseek` call to set the stream position to zero each time you draw a frame.  I've found two ways to do this:

- Use [RandomAccessFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead of OutputStream / FileOutputStream, and call [seek(long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) to seek the file.
- Call [FileOutputStream.getChannel()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#getChannel()), and then use [position(long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position(long)) to seek the file.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Output Stream to RandomAccessFile fixed all of my problems. I bet the stream wasn't working because it can't seek to position 0. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking on the green check outline to the left of the answer. This helps others by confirming that solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you flush your output with [flush](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()) (from OutputStream)?

Comment: @Alf - it should make no difference, since a FileOutputStream is not buffered.  IIRC, the `flush()` method is implemented as a no-op in this case.